# Removing the square brackets, commas and single quote?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3. I am trying to return the function so that It would take a single word and convert it to Cow Latin. I want to get rid of the square bracket, the comma and single apostrophes when I run my function.

My function is:

```
alpha = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
def cow_latinify_word(word):
    if word[0].lower() in alpha:
        lista = (word.lower())
        return lista[1:] + lista[0] + "oo"
    else:
        return word + "moo"

def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split();
    return [cow_latinify_word(word) for word in words]
```

when I test the function with

```
cow_latin = cow_latinify_sentence("Cook me some eggs")
print(cow_latin)
```

I get `['ookcoo', 'emoo', 'omesoo', 'eggsmoo']` but I want `ookcoo emoo omesoo eggsmoo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `' '.join(list)` for concatenating the list elements into a string.

In your code:

```
alpha = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
def cow_latinify_word(word):
    if word[0].lower() in alpha:
        lista = (word.lower())
        return lista[1:] + lista[0] + "oo"
    else:
        return word + "moo"

def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split();
    return ' '.join([cow_latinify_word(word) for word in words])
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add an asterisk before the variable name to unpack the list and feed its elements as positional arguments to `print`.

```
print(*cow_latin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `cow_latinify_sentence` returns a list of strings you need to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with spaces to get your desired output:

```
print(" ".join(cow_latin))
```

Comment: When I use the print function, I get:
ookcoo emoo omesoo eggsmoo
None

Comment: @Saxasianguy Using your code with my small modification I get the result `ookcoo emoo omesoo eggsmoo`. Is the code in your question exactly the same code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Let's define our variables:

```
>>> consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
>>> sentence = "Cook me some eggs"
```

Find the cow-latin:

```
>>> ' '.join(word[1:] + word[0] + 'oo' if word[0] in consonants else word + 'moo' for word in sentence.lower().split())
'ookcoo emoo omesoo eggsmoo'
```